# How do I end loop when 0 is entered?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where the user will keep entering numbers until 0 is entered using loops. It will then display the largest number entered, the smallest number entered, and the average of all the numbers. This is what I have to start with:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;                                                    

public class MaxMinAvg
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        String inString = " ";
        int count = 0;


        inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");

                                                                                //perform until the end of file
        while(inString.length() != 0)
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("record " + count + " is " + inString);

                                                                             // second read
            inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");

        }                                                                   // end while loop

        System.out.println("All done");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to compare the input string with your exit condition:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;                                                    

public class MaxMinAvg
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        String inString = " ";
        int count = 0;


        inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");

                                                                                //perform until the end of file
        while(inString.length() != 0 && !inString.equal("0"))
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("record " + count + " is " + inString);

                                                                             // second read
            inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");

        }                                                                   // end while loop

        System.out.println("All done");

   }
}
```

Comment: I get a compile error error: cannot find symbol
        while(inString.length() != 0 && !inString.equal('0'))
                                                                      ^

Comment: this is because there is no method name - `equal`, it is `equals()`. Inside `equals()` method you should check `String` not `Character`. Therefore the second condition would be like this - `!inString.equal("0")`

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you don't need `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");` twice. Call it once inside the `while` loop.

**Second**, define an infinite `while` loop - `while(true)` since you don't know how many times user will give input.

**Third**, as to stop the `loop` based on input `0`, put the logic inside the loop.

- `trim()` the input, user could insert a blank space before or after the unmber
- convert the input into `int`
- check equality `==` of user given input with `0`
- `break` the loop

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String inString = "";

        int count = 0;

        while(true) {

            inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");

            count++;

            System.out.println("record " + count + " is " + inString);

            if (Integer.parseInt(inString.trim()) == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("All done");
    }
```

Comment: how would I go about printing the largest number entered, the smallest number entered, and the average?

Comment: I assume you know how to use `List` data structure. First, define a `List` of `Integer` type, then add each of the user input to that `List`. Then using that `list` you could easily find the largest, smallest and the average.

Comment: I am very new to programming, I don't really know how that would look like.

Comment: Please follow these links to learn about array and list - [Java Array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) , [Java List](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) , [Java List](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm). These basic data-structure concept. I could do the code for you but you could understand that until you learn the concept. There are lots of youtube tutorial as well. Type the keyword java list or java array! :)

Comment: But if you are so in short of time you can see [this stackoverflow q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381346/java-find-the-largest-number-in-a-list-of-a-number-of-integers-that-the-user-ha). This is very similar to what you want.

Comment: I  am in short of time. I just need to get the min and max of user inputs. Then the average.

Comment: @JoshuaRodas have you figured it out?